Is it possible to checkout git from Jenkins controller instead of separate agent but still execute on the agent?
We have our git repo and Jenkins controller in our internal network. For agents we'd like to use Azure containers, but as it turns out agents need direct access to the git repository. Is it possible to make the controller check out the repo and relay it to the agent?

Nothing like that is supported by Jenkins natively, not even close. Networking concerns are completely outside of Jenkins scope, so you would have to improvise. A couple of options that require Jenkins and nothing else:

Stash/unstash. As the documentation says you can use it up to 5-100 MB, but beyond that it's just not going to work. On the plus side - it doesn't leave a lot of junk in your build history

archiveArtifacts/copyArtifacts. Limits are pretty generous - I worked with gigabytes. But copyArtifacts is an extra plugin, and artifacts are saved as a part of your build history, so it adds up.


Obviously you can save/restore using whatever external service you have (Azure Blob Storage?) and if your repos are small it's tenable, but not scaleable, your Jenkins server will quickly become the bottleneck.
